# Converting <img> alt text to image caption node

Tags: html, jscript

```js
function altTextToImageCaption() {
  let imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var att = imgs[i].attributes.getNamedItem('alt');
    if (!att) continue;
    var alt = att.value;
    if (!alt) continue;
    if (!alt.startsWith('Fig ')) continue;
    var cap = document.createElement('div');
    cap.setAttribute('class', 'imageCaption');
    cap.appendChild(document.createTextNode(alt));
    document.body.insertBefore(cap, imgs[i].nextSibling);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="altTextToImageCaption()">
  <h1>Image Caption No Workie</h1>
  <img src="https://www.easyrgb.com/look/home_logo.png" alt="Fig 1. First caption.">

  <div>
  <img src="https://www.easyrgb.com/look/home_logo.png" alt="Fig 2. Second caption.">
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to come up with a jscript function which inserts a caption text underneath all images in an html document which contain an `alt` attribute which starts with "Fig ". Seems to work except when the `img` node is inside a `div` or `span`. In that case there's an exception:

`Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node."`

Comment: `imgs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(cap, imgs[i]);` maybe?

Comment: @AlonEitan well, that puts the image caption _above_ the image. I need it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest changing the line:

```
document.body.insertBefore(cap, imgs[i].nextSibling);
```

to:

```
imgs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(cap, imgs[i].nextSibling);
```

This ensures that the `<div>` is always appended after the `<img>` itself, regardless of where it appears in the DOM:

```js
function altTextToImageCaption() {
  let imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var att = imgs[i].attributes.getNamedItem('alt');
    if (!att) continue;
    var alt = att.value;
    if (!alt) continue;
    if (!alt.startsWith('Fig ')) continue;
    var cap = document.createElement('div');
    cap.setAttribute('class', 'imageCaption');
    cap.appendChild(document.createTextNode(alt));
    imgs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(cap, imgs[i].nextSibling);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="altTextToImageCaption()">
  <h1>Image Caption No Workie</h1>
  <img src="https://www.easyrgb.com/look/home_logo.png" alt="Fig 1. First caption.">

  <div>
    <img src="https://www.easyrgb.com/look/home_logo.png" alt="Fig 2. Second caption.">
  </div>
</body>
```

However, while that solves the problem I'd also completely rewrite your function to the following – and also use unobtrusive JavaScript – to the following:

```js
// using an Arrow function to create the function as a const:
const altTextToImageCaption = () => {
  // using document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve only
  // <img> elements that have an 'alt' attribute that starts
 // with the string "Fig "
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('img[alt^="Fig "]');

  // using NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
  // NodeList of <img> element-nodes:
  images.forEach(
    // using an anonymous Arrow function:
    (img) => {
      // retrieving the attribute-value of the 'alt'
      // attribute, and removing leading/trailing
      // white-space:
      let alt = img.alt.trim(),
        // creating a <div> element:
        div = document.createElement('div');

      // using the Element.classList API to add the
      // 'imageCaption' class-name:
      div.classList.add('imageCaption');
      // using ParentNode.append() to append
      // the string:
      div.append(alt);

      // navigating to the <img> element's parent,
      // and using ParentNode.insertBefore() to
      // insert the new ('div') content before the
      // next-sibling of the <img> element:
      img.parentNode.insertBefore(div, img.nextSibling);
    });
}

// binding the event-handling in JavaScript rather than inline
// event-binding; here we bind the altTextToImageCaption() function
// as the event-handler for the 'DOMContentLoaded' event:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', altTextToImageCaption);
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Image Caption No Workie</h1>
  <img src="https://www.easyrgb.com/look/home_logo.png" alt="Fig 1. First caption.">

  <div>
    <img src="https://www.easyrgb.com/look/home_logo.png" alt="Fig 2. Second caption.">
  </div>
</body>
```

As a belated edit, I'd also suggest – if you wish to pair an `<img>` and a caption – that you use a `<figure>` element, with a `<figcaption>`:

```js
// a simple alias for document.createElement() that also allows properties to be
// passed into the created-element:
const create = (tag, props) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
// using an Arrow function to create the function as a const:
const altTextToImageCaption = () => {
  // using document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve only
  // <img> elements that have an 'alt' attribute that starts
  // with the string "Fig "
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('img[alt^="Fig "]');

  // using NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
  // NodeList of <img> element-nodes:
  images.forEach(
    // using an anonymous Arrow function:
    (img) => {
        // retrieving the content of the 'alt' attribute, removing leading
      // and trailing white-space with String.prototype.trim():
        let altText = img.getAttribute('alt').trim(),
            // creating a <figure> element:
            figure = create('figure'),
          // creating a <figcaption> element, and passing in the
          // text of the 'alt' attribute as the text-content of
          // the created element:
            figCaption = create('figcaption',{textContent: altText});
      
      // using Element.append() to append the <figcaption> to the
      // <figure>:
      figure.append(figCaption);
      // using Element.before() to insert the created <figure>
      // element before the current <img>:
      img.before(figure);
      // using Element.prepend() to insert the <img> element to
      // the <figure> element, as its first-child (moving it from
      // its original position):
      figure.prepend(img);
    });
}

// binding the event-handling in JavaScript rather than inline
// event-binding; here we bind the altTextToImageCaption() function
// as the event-handler for the 'DOMContentLoaded' event:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', altTextToImageCaption);
```

```html
<h1>Image Caption No Workie</h1>
<img src="https://www.easyrgb.com/look/home_logo.png" alt="Fig 1. First caption.">

<div>
  <img src="https://www.easyrgb.com/look/home_logo.png" alt="Fig 2. Second caption.">
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know that you can pass `null` as the second parameter for `insertBefore` :) Nice to learn new things

Comment: It's one of those rare features that seems surprisingly well thought out in anticipation of inadvertent potential errors :)

Comment: Thank you for the excellent advice. I'm in my first week of javascript and am still confused at most every turn.

Comment: If you can use `Element.append()`, then you can probably also use [`ChildNode.after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `parentNode` of the image to call `insertBefore` on.

As an extra clean-up you can use `for..of` to clean up the code a bit.

I propose:

```js
function altTextToImageCaption() {
  let imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
  for(let img of imgs) {
    var att = img.attributes.getNamedItem('alt')
    if (!att) continue
    let alt = att.value
    if (!alt) continue
    if (!alt.startsWith('Fig ')) continue
    let cap = document.createElement('div')
    cap.setAttribute('class', 'imageCaption')
    cap.appendChild(document.createTextNode(alt))
    img.parentNode.insertBefore(cap, img.nextSibling)
  }
}
```